# How to inject full HTML doc, then DOM-manipulate injected code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

My build is running Angular, so I have jqLite available for jQuery-esque DOM manipulation. Here's my current predicament:

I have a full HTML document stored in a database or elsewhere. I'm trying to inject that HTML into an iframe, so the browser can render the injected HTML accurately. Currently, I'm doing this by binding `srcdoc` iframe attribute to a var in my model – and the injected page renders beautifully.

The kicker: after injection, I want to be able to select and modify specific elements within that injection. How do I go about doing that? Do I need to include the injected HTML using a different method?

Thanks!

Comment: A demo might help. Also curious why traditional iFrame methods can't be used

Comment: Essentially, what's being stored in the database are templates that have certain editable regions. We'll be using Angular to manipulate those editable regions "live", but due to the nature of the project we need to use all of the HTML (not a partial).

Comment: understand that part, but not hard to get inside an iframe using script so not really clear where the problems lie.

Comment: The HTML within an iFrame is untouchable from outside that iFrame. The iFrame thus needs to be a self contained Angular app.